# how to apply if and OR if or condition in td tag in html file

Tags: html, spock-reports

I am using athaydes reports for my geb spock html report. I am trying to modify the html report to get the status of the test case. For that I have added new column as 'Final Column'
Below is html I am using:

```
<table class="summary-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Features</th>
        <th>Failed</th>
        <th>Errors</th>
        <th>Skipped</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Final Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% data.each { name, map ->
    def s = map.stats%>
    <tr class="${s.errors ? 'error' : ''} ${s.failures ? 'failure' : ''} ">
        <td><a href="${name}.html">$name</a></td>
        <td>${s.totalRuns}</td>
        <td>${s.failures}</td>
        <td>${s.errors}</td>
        <td>${s.skipped}</td>
        <td>${fmt.toTimeDuration(s.time)}</td>
        <td if="${s.totalRuns} != 0" ? 'PASS' : 'FAILED >${s.totalRuns = 0 ? 'PASS' : 'FAILED' }</td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now my requirement is that if "`${s.failures}`" and "`${s.errors}`" and "`${s.skipped}`" are equal to zero,  then only the value for column should come as "PASS" else it should be "FAILED".

I tried something like  `<td if="${s.totalRuns} != 0" ? 'PASS' : 'FAILED >${s.totalRuns = 0 ? 'PASS' : 'FAILED' }</td>`  however this solution is not working as I am very new to html.

Can you please help me on this front. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet, to show FAILED if failures, errors or skipped tests occured, and PASS if not:

```
<td>${ s.failures || s.errors || s.skipped ? 'FAILED' : 'PASS' }</td>
```

As `s.failures` and the others are integers, we don't need to explicitly check if they are more than 0.

If you do also want to hide the value if `s.totalRuns` is zero, you could add another condition. General rule of thumb: Everything between `<% ... %>` can be any Groovy code. There might be a cleaner solutions than this one, but it does the trick:

```
<td>
    <% if (s.totalRuns) { %>
        ${ s.failures || s.errors || s.skipped ? 'FAILED' : 'PASS' }
    <% } %>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi TIlman, Thanks so much. Your first solution is working absolutely fine for me. Thanks!